# Retrieving current stack pointer from /proc/pid/stat

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I'm executing a basic C program using gdb. I have a break point at the start of `main()`. After running the code, gdb breaks at main() as expected. 
Now if I examine the stack pointer register (rsp), i'm seeing

```
0x7fffffffe170: 0x00000000.
```

When I retrieve the same information using `cat /proc/17232/stat | cut -d" " -f29/proc` (where 17232 is pid for this process), I'm seeing:

```
140737488347112 (which in hex is: 0x7fffffffdfe8).
```

How come we see a different value of current stack pointer from gdb. And also, why gdb is showing contents of rsp as NULL (0x00000000)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing the *rsp* register (on 64b cpus) from `/proc`

```
(gdb) info register rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffe480   0x7fffffffe480
```

gives indeed a different value compared to the one from `/proc`

```
me@linux:~$ cat /proc/22219/stat | cut -d" " -f29 | perl -e 'print(sprintf("%x\n",<>));'
7fffffffe338
```

since *gdb* has to force an [interruption](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Advanced_Interrupts) in the program at the beginning of the *main* function in order to take over the execution, and a minimal set of data (return address, some registers backup) is saved onto the stack. *gdb* then, uses its own stack not to overflow the program one, and makes the necessary adjustment operations when you request to view the registers, or work on the stack data - and does not show the internal *gdb* cooking. However `/proc` shows the real data, unchanged.

The "real" *rsp* from `/proc` is actually slightly less than the *gdb* one, since on x86 cpus the stack grows downward.

As for the *null* value, it didn't happen during my tests

```
(gdb) x 0x7fffffffe480
0x7fffffffe480: 0xffffe578
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Will try to figure out why the memory is shown as null in my test.